How to prove that such a n exists such that $f_n(x)=x+n$
This is a sample question from ISI-$2023$,
let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions for $n\ge 1$, suppose $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists n_x \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $f_{n_x}(x)=x+n_x$. Prove that there exists $a<b$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_m(x)=x+m$, $\forall x \in [a,b]$
I saw that given any interval, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that for uncountably many $x$ in that interval $f_n(x)=n+x$ and I tried several other things also, but was not able to get a correct proof... This seems like an easy problem, but wasn't able to solve
How to solve this? kindly help.

@KaleBhodre Its Indian Statistical Institute, It's a sample question from its entrance examination

@KaleBhodre jrf

Assume no such interval exists.
Partition $\mathbb{R}$ into countably many disjoint sets, $A_n$, where $A_n$ is the set of all $x$ for which $n$ is the first number satisfying $f_n(x)=x+n$.
If $A_n$ is dense in a neighbourhood, then, by continuity, $f_n(x)=x+n$ for the closure of that entire neighbourhood, which would give us an interval. So this can't happen, and each $A_n$ must be nowhere dense.
Implying $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of nowhere dense sets- i.e. a meagre set. Which is false.
